# Formula to pull numbers out of number string

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a large list of numbers all containing 14 numbers each. I need to pull out the numbers in the 4th and 5th position from the left. I have tried using =Left with some subtraction but it is not working like I need it to. Any thoughts?

Comment: Have you tried using `=VALUE(column)` to make sure it is treated as a number and not text?

Comment: try using `=mid(...)`

Comment: @gtwebb That worked perfectly. I knew there was an easy answer I just could not figure it out.

Comment: @gtwebb If you post an answer I will accept it to close the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [mid](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/MID-MIDB-functions-d5f9e25c-d7d6-472e-b568-4ecb12433028) function

From help:

> **Description**
>
> MID returns a specific number of characters from a text string,
>   starting at the position you specify, based on the number of
>   characters you specify.
>
> **Syntax**
>
> MID(text, start_num, num_chars)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a combo of Left() and Right():

```
dim NumberString = "12345678901234"
dim Slice
dim TempSlice

TempSlice = Left(NumberString, 5)
Slice = Right(TempSlice, 2)
```